# How to access UIImageView to set image using Picker Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm adding a button to a UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell programmatically. However, how can I access the original imageView so I can set the selected image to the UIImageView?

My code:

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SampleCell") as! UITableViewCell

     if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 175))
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(110, 30, 100, 100))
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "Camera-50.png")

        let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        button.setImage(myImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "getImage", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(button)
        cell.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    return cell
}



func getImage() {


    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.delegate = self

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    //need to access imageView to set image

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you could technically access the `UIImageView` from your `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method by storing it in a class variable, you should instead set the `UIImageView`'s image in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method using the image returned from the image picker, ex:

```
var image:UIImage?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SampleCell") as! UITableViewCell

     if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 175))
        if let image = image {
            imageView.image = image
        }

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(110, 30, 100, 100))
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "Camera-50.png")

        let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer()
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

        button.setImage(myImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "getImage", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        cell.addSubview(button)
        cell.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    return cell
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Note: `didFinishPickingImage:` has been deprecated since iOS 3.0 so I'm using `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` in its place.

Comment: Thanks Lyndsey! I'm just a little confused about global variables...aren't they supposed to be avoided at all costs really? I posted this question on SF yesterday but I'm still confused about when/if I should use globals.

Comment: How would one access the `UIImageView` from the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`?